# How can I install Pillow on OpenShift (V2)

Tags: django, python-2.7, openshift, python-imaging-library

I want to install **Pillow** in openShift. I tried adding the dependency in **setup.py** but, it didn't help me.
I also tried to login the remote server (rhc ssh app_name) and run the command `pip install pillow`. But, that was also a failure.
Then, how can I install Pillow on OpenShift v2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ssh in
source ~/python/virtenv/bin/activate
pip install --log $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/inst.log https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/archive/master.zip
```

Comment: What you mean by **ssh in** ?